# Set Wordpress settings programmatically

Tags: options

Is it possible to set certain settings from the theme functions file for example the setting `Enable threaded (nested) comments` ca I set it to allow `2` as the answer without having the user go into the admin panel and setting it for there wordpress comment settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am satisfied with Nikolay Yordanov's answer. Just generalizing the solution.

Yes, we can update WordPress options programmatically. WordPress saves options in **wp_options** table. **wp_options** holds two rows **option_name** and **option_value** to store key and value respectively. We need right **option_name** and a way to save value in **wp_options** table.

As we know, we can update threaded comments option by going to **wp-admin/options-discussion.php**. By opening the page options-discussion.php in a code editor, you can easily found the required option_name to update.

[image: WordPress Options-Discussion]

Now, if one can get an option, also one can update it. What you need is WordPress function [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option).

**Final PHP Snippet**

```
function update_thread_comments_depth($depth){
    //Validation check
    if(is_int($depth) && 0 < $depth){

        update_option('thread_comments_depth', $width);

        return true; //success
    }

    return false; //failure
}
```

Hope, it will help to update other options as well, just open right file in code editor and find the required option name.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do something like this which will always reset the option to 2:

```
add_action('init', 'update_comment_depth');
function update_comment_depth() {
  update_option('thread_comments_depth', 2);
}
```